# Check if dataframe column contain string type in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe as such:

[image]

If column [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUDjc.png) is a string, i need column 2, else column 1 still.

Tried this:

```
df.loc[df[1].dtype != np.number, df[1]] = df.loc[df[1].dtype != np.number, df[1]]
```

But it gives me a key error: True

Comment: What do you mean "I need column 2, else column 1 still"? Do you want to replace string values in column 1 with the numerical ones in column 2 (same row)? Can you provide the desired output?

Comment: Do you want to replace string values in column 1 with the numerical ones in column 2 (same row)? => yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List comprehension might come handy in such case, check out:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df[0] = ["some", "dummy", "data", "filling", "up"]
df[1] = ["0","foo","2","3","bar"]
df[2] = [9,8,7,6,5]
df[3] = [item[1][1] if item[1][1].isnumeric() else item[1][2] for item in df.iterrows() ]
```

Assign new row with item from row 1 if it is numeric, else use item from row 2.

Answer (score 1):

This is what you need.

I assume your dataframe name is df.

```py
for i, a in enumerate(df[1]):
  if type(a) == str:
    df.iloc[i, 1] = df.iloc[i, 2]
df
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your desired output is to replace all non-numerical values from column 1 with the ones from column 2, this is how you do it.

Assume your initial dataframe is this:

```py
>>> df
        0     1  2
0    some   foo  1
1  random    -2  2
2    text   bar  3
3    some   NaN  4
4  random    -5  5
5    text    -6  6
6    some  None  7
```

You first call [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) on your desired column, specifying to put non-numeric values to NaN.

After this, you fill these NaNs with the matching elements from column 2, and (optional) cast to int the Series obtained.

```py
>>> df['1'] = pd.to_numeric(df['1'], errors='coerce').fillna(df['2']).astype(int)
>>> df
        0  1  2
0    some  1  1
1  random -2  2
2    text  3  3
3    some  4  4
4  random -5  5
5    text -6  6
6    some  7  7
```